# smart match operator for hash of hash

Tags: perl, hash, match

I want to match keys of a **hash of hash** with regexp .

```
$line=" Cluster(A,B):A(T) M(S)";
$reg="Cluster";
my ( $cluster, $characters ) = split (/:/,$line);
$HoH{$cluster}={split /[( )]+/,$characters } ;
foreach $value(keys %HoH){
    foreach $characters (keys %{$HoH{$cluster}}){
        print "$value:$characters\n" if    /$reg/ ~~ %HoH;
    }
}
```

now Output is :

Cluster(A,B):A

Cluster(A,B):M

This code is works fine with this sample data,but not with real data!! my data is more complicated but the structure is the same I was wondering if there is some other ways to do this

Comment: Try to describe what you need to achieve without relying on the smartmatch operator. Show us an example of your hash of hashes where you point out which keys you are trying to match.

Comment: The updated code would print out *all* entries if just one of the keys in the outer hash matches /Cluster/. Is that intended?

Comment: You still haven't said what it is you want your code to do.  Describing what you want -- precisely -- is the first step towards telling a computer what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you want just

```
print "something\n" if exists $HoH{regexp}
```

or maybe

```
print "something\n" if grep /regexp/, keys %HoH
```

but if neither of these are correct then you need to explain better what you need, and give some examples

Comment: The latter condition should be equivalent to `/regexp/ ~~ %HoH` according to the documentation coming with perl 5.16.0.

Answer (score 1):

This is under documented, and I don't grok exactly what the issue is, but the smart match operator works better with references to arrays and hashes. So you may have better luck with

```
/$reg/ ~~ \%Hoh
```

Answer (score 1):

SmartMatch is currently complicated, unwieldy and surprising. Don't use it, at least not now. There's talk by the main developers of perl to either greatly simplify it or remove it completely. Either way it won't do what you're asking it to do in the future, so don't rely on it doing that now.

Being more explicit about what you want is better anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, your bug is here:

```
foreach $characters (keys %{$HoH{$cluster}}) {
```

which should read

```
foreach $characters (keys %{$HoH{$value}}) {
```

.  Probably.