# Parse an array and see if a string matches

Tags: regex, perl

Hi I want to parse an `@array` which has strings and see if `"This is bird"` string is present or not. If present do something else return. I am doing it in perl.

I have used `if($string ~~ @array)`, But no output even if there is a matching string present. It is unable to compare both strings if I use this.
The `@array` can have any number of strings, even 1 string sometimes.  Is there any other way I can do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the smart-match operator (`~~`) to look for an element in a list, [the syntax is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12426511/168657)

```
$string ~~ \@array
```

Since [using the smart-match operator is dicey](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36502331/168657), some alternatives that do not depend on it are to use grep

```
if (grep { $_ eq $string } @array) { ... }
```

and `List::Util::first` or `List::Util::any`

```
use List::Util 'first';
if (first { $_ eq $string } @array) { ... }

use List::Util 'any';
if (any{ $_ eq $string } @array) { ... }
```

Comment: I want to make my question more clear as this still didn't work. The `@array` which I have contains the matching strings from a file. I have it as my @array = grep -Fx 'this is bird' file.txt"); I am basically doing this to know if that string is present or not. If the array contains the matching string then I want to edit the file.

Comment: You should include sample input and desired output if you want to be understood better.

Comment: Actually, `$string ~~ @array` is fine.